# Generating Java stubs from the GUI Layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When creating an app in Android Studio, I first create the GUI layout.  Is there a way to generate Java stubs for all the possible user actions on this layout?  For example, in B4A (Basic for Android), after creating the GUI layout (with all the buttons, checkboxes etc.), B4A automatically creates Basic code stubs for all the possible user actions generated by the layout.  It also automatically adds all the libraries needed by the layout